# How does Django know to call the index?

Tags: python, django

I just started learning Django and I am a bit confused. I'm following the official documentation and this is the code:

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**polls/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

**polls/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

I am mainly confused that if I add more functions in polls/views.py, how will using inclde('polls.urls') know that I wish to call the index function or some other function?

Link for the documentation page that I am following: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: The full path for the `views.index` is `'polls/' + ''`, so it appends the two. If you make an extra `path('foo/', views.other_view, name='other_view')`, then that path pattern will be `'polls/'+'foo/' = 'polls/foo/'`, so it will disambiguate between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it constructs a list of paths (strings) that it tries to build up and then find which you wanted

so paths in polls for `""` and `foobar` would lead django to try to match up to the following urls

```
polls/
polls/foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

The full path for the `views.index` is `'polls/' + ''` and thus `'polls/'`, so it appends the two.
If you make an extra path:

```
# polls/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
    path('foo/', views.other_view, name='other-view')
]
```

then that path pattern will be `'polls/'+'foo/' = 'polls/foo/'`, so it will disambiguate between the two.

If you thus visit `polls/`, then the first path will match and thus "*fire*" `index`. If you visit `polls/foo`, then the `other-view` will "*fire*".

Comment: I get that part. Can you please explain what I would add in mysite/urls.py in order to use the function 'foo'?

Comment: @duskdusk13: that would be `path('polls/foo/', views.other_view, name='other-view')`. You thus can use the same prefix. Django will enumerate over all the possible urls top-to-bottom and only "fire" a view, if it matches completely.

Comment: @duskdusk13: this is normally done since all the views of an app share a common prefix. It is thus a way to encapsulate logic in a module. Especially since Django apps are sometimes used as third party plugins, so in that case one should plugin all the views by the `urls.py` exported by that third party app.

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot of sense now!